# Downloading supported file using Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ie-mobile

I am having the following problem when using windows phone.

I have created a handler Download.ashx which takes query ID that I am using to retrieve data from database. Pretty simple stuff and it works on desktop browsers. However when I am trying to use that same way on windows phone 7 I get an error "can't download file windows phone doesn't support this file type"

After quick search on google, I found that WP7 doesn't support this kind of way for downloading files. They should be direct links, for downloading to work.

So my question is: What is the best way to go around this problem, or is there any?

Edit: Oh, and the software I am writing is C# web application that used on mobile devices. WP7.5 is the one having problems

Comment: How do you have tried to download the file? As I can remember (and also MSDN says) there is a DownloadFileAsync Method at the WebClient. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.100).aspx or something i have found: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/9853a64f-4eba-4970-b6aa-fcff408ce49f/

Comment: What is the MIME type of the file you're downloading?

Comment: I have tested it on "image/png" and "image/jpeg" and the url I am trying to use is like http://mysite.com/Download.ashx?ID=58